# Two column flexbox overflowing two columns when considering error messages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form in which we want the layout to be two columns of inputs in which the first column is inputs 1, 2, 3, 4 and the second column is inputs 5, 6, 7, 8. We want it to be this way because when considering mobile displays, we want a single column of inputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Now, as you can see from the example below, I've put a `max-height` on the `ol` tag in order to constrain the inputs to two columns. Everything works nicely when moving from desktop to mobile displays.

The problem comes when form validation kicks in and an error message is displayed. The error message needs to appear below the input and when it does, it increases the height of each flex item. Now, becomes I am constrained by the `max-height` property, the resulting layout is no longer two columns.

I can't easily play the `max-height` property to accommodate two columns with and without the error messages showing. Without the error messages, if the max height is two large, then it is no longer 4 inputs per column.

Is there a way in CSS to make it so that I can keep 4 inputs to a column even with the added height due to the error message?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vz95fh6x/

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
submitButton.onclick = validateForm;

/* Checks to see if the form inputs are empty. If so, display error message */
function validateForm() {
    const inputItems = document.getElementsByClassName('input-item')
    
    for (const item of inputItems) {
        const input = item.children[1]
        if (input.value === '') {
            item.children[2].innerHTML = 'Enter an input'
        }
    }
}
```

```css
ol {
    background-color: lightblue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    ol {
        display: block;
        max-height: none;
    }
}

ol li {
    flex: 1 auto;
}

.error {
    color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item1">Item 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="item1" name="item1">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item2">Item 2</label>
                <input type="text" id="item2" name="item2">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item3">Item 3</label>
                <input type="text" id="item3" name="item3">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item4">Item 4</label>
                <input type="text" id="item4" name="item4">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item5">Item 5</label>
                <input type="text" id="item5" name="item5">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item6">Item 6</label>
                <input type="text" id="item6" name="item6">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item7">Item 7</label>
                <input type="text" id="item7" name="item7">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="input-item">
                <label for="item8">Item 8</label>
                <input type="text" id="item8" name="item8">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <br />

    <button id="button" onclick={validateForm()}>
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is intended to be one-dimensional. If you have both columns and rows, I'd suggest using `display: grid` instead. Then you can add a media query that changes the wrapper from two grid columns to one grid column on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use flexbox to make this go well responsive wise. You don't need the max-width element, just use a `@media` selector to make the flex direction go from row to column when the screen width is `787px` (Mobile resolution)

I also inserted two `<div>` elements within the `<ol>` so that flexbox can use those two `<div>` elements as two columns on PC and iPad.

PS: Make sure to click "Expand Snippet" to see the responsive query go to work because if you run the snippet within my post the media query will be used. OR check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FUZIION/coepz094/1/)

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
submitButton.onclick = validateForm;

/* Checks to see if the form inputs are empty. If so, display error message */
function validateForm() {
  const inputItems = document.getElementsByClassName('input-item')

  for (const item of inputItems) {
    const input = item.children[1]
    if (input.value === '') {
      item.children[2].innerHTML = 'Enter an input'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ol {
  background-color: lightblue;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ol div {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

ol li {
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.error {
  color: firebrick;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 787px /* mobile */) {
  ol {
    flex-direction: column!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol>
    <div>
      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item1">Item 1</label>
          <input type="text" id="item1" name="item1">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item2">Item 2</label>
          <input type="text" id="item2" name="item2">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item3">Item 3</label>
          <input type="text" id="item3" name="item3">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item4">Item 4</label>
          <input type="text" id="item4" name="item4">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item5">Item 5</label>
          <input type="text" id="item5" name="item5">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item6">Item 6</label>
          <input type="text" id="item6" name="item6">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item7">Item 7</label>
          <input type="text" id="item7" name="item7">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="input-item">
          <label for="item8">Item 8</label>
          <input type="text" id="item8" name="item8">
          <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ol>
  <br />

  <button id="button" onclick={validateForm()}>
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

After reading your comment regarding the flexbox solution not being kosher, I looked around for a little bit and found that this is also an option. You can simply define how many columns a `<ol>` or `<ul>` has by using the css element `column-count`.

[For more information about column-count click here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
submitButton.onclick = validateForm;

/* Checks to see if the form inputs are empty. If so, display error message */
function validateForm() {
  const inputItems = document.getElementsByClassName('input-item')

  for (const item of inputItems) {
    const input = item.children[1]
    if (input.value === '') {
      item.children[2].innerHTML = 'Enter an input'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ol {
  background-color: lightblue;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  column-count: 2;
}

.error {
  color: firebrick;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 787px /* mobile */) {
  ol {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item1">Item 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="item1" name="item1">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item2">Item 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="item2" name="item2">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item3">Item 3</label>
        <input type="text" id="item3" name="item3">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item4">Item 4</label>
        <input type="text" id="item4" name="item4">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item5">Item 5</label>
        <input type="text" id="item5" name="item5">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item6">Item 6</label>
        <input type="text" id="item6" name="item6">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item7">Item 7</label>
        <input type="text" id="item7" name="item7">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="input-item">
        <label for="item8">Item 8</label>
        <input type="text" id="item8" name="item8">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <br />

  <button id="button" onclick={validateForm()}>
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

So there you have it, two solutions to responsively style a `<ol>`

Comment: This is a nifty solution. My only issue with it is that it uses `div`s within the `ol` tag which is not kosher HTML and will not pass accessibility checks or the code review that my company does.

Comment: Totally understand, I'll take a look again see what I can dig up that is kosher.

Comment: Added a kosher solution

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for putting this together. Today I learned about the `column-count` property.

Comment: Happy to help man! Good luck with the job!